# Calculating the volume of cutted cone by a plane

Tags: integration, volume

[image][image]I need to calculate the volume bounded by the plane: $x+y+z=5$ and by the cone $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$, som my V that i'm $dv$-ing on it is cutted cone in non simetric way (i can find the equation of the intersection, but it dont give me anything).

As i see it, i need to find D and do the double integral on the substraction between my plane and the cone, am i right ?

And in that case, if i understand correctly, i need to find my D, but because it is a cone, i need only to find my R and i dont understnd which is it and how to find him (do i take the max or min - it is a cutted cone, so its upper part is by "diagonal" if we look at it in 3D).
I hope i explain myself good enough.

Comment: Is the problem correct? There doesn't seem exist a bounded volume between them.

Comment: Actually, I did notice that, but i though the volume is between (0,0,0) and the cutted cone part at the top, although there is the other side of the cone. I checked it, it is correct. Do you mind to draw it (if oyu know how), why you see it as unexcited ? 
I mean the upper part is infinite, so it isnt it, so i thought it is the part from the origin to the cutted part, as i said.

Comment: The intersection of the cone and the plane projected onto $xy$ plane is $2xy-10x-10y+25=0$. Through some linear transformation I got a hyperbola $4u^2-v^2=25$. That's why I think the volume should have no bound. I'll think about it more when I have more time. And I am not sure what you meant by "from the origin to the cutted part".

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really constitute an answer. I can delete it if it is not appropriate. I just want to show the following picture:

[image]

You can see this really doesn't enclose any volume to calculate.

Comment: How do i upload a picture ? Found it. It seems you are right. Maybe it is a mistake in the exercise itself. It isnt exist indeed.

Comment: Here, try look it itself: http://web.monroecc.edu/manila/webfiles/calcNSF/JavaCode/CalcPlot3D.htm
(Activate java, if it doest on, for this tool). In the equation of z, put +- sqrt. 
And you can zoom in and out for smaller and bigger values of x,y,z. 
Just to verify our assumption, that it isnt exist.

Comment: @user183297: Great picture!

Comment: So, as we see, we dont have a cover the bottom and tthe upper part, it is infinite. Because it is bounded in both sides, but not bounded on top and the opposite side, right ?

Comment: @user183297: Right. I do think the problem is wrong.